# Обращение к полю класса в методе

Tags: python, ооп, pygame

Когда я стреляю(shoot) появляется ошибка, типа ну нет такого массива bullets, типа некуда мне пихать твои патроны! Но при этом bullets вроде бы явно описан. 
 Это какая-то ошибка или у меня пробелы ООП?

```
class player:

    def __init__(self, x, y, speed, max_bullets):
        self.bullets = []
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed
        self.max_bullets = max_bullets
    def shoot(self, x, y):
        bullets.append(bullet(x, y, bullet_speed))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли добавить `self.` к `bullets` в методе:

```python
def shoot(self, x, y):
    self.bullets.append(bullet(x, y, bullet_speed))
```

Comment: ок, понятно, спасибо